# How do APCs find their specific T-cells in the lymph nodes?

Tags: immunology, medicine, immune-system

My understanding is that when an APC (more specifically a dendritic cell) encounters an antigen in the periphery, it ingests it and presents it on its surface. It then migrates to lymph nodes to activate the T-cell that has the specific receptor for this antigen.

Now, I know that T-cells circulate throughout the body, but given the amount of the cells in a lymph node, and the fact that only a few T-cells are specific for a given antigen, it *seems* to me highly improbable for the APC to meet the specific T-cell.

Is it really that the APCs randomly check every T-cell there? If so, do we know how long would that take? Or is there a way to quickly locate the specific T-cell?

Comment: Can you give some link to Janeway's which is available online or any other reference? - I think it might be some misunderstanding to assume that ther is only one singel (stem) T o B cell that fits. I think it's a "bunch" of stem cells that shares one specifity, so chances are not that bad, to meet.  What's more, there might be polymorphy, i.e. several affinities that fit. Wonder if  you ever came across such or similar argument.